# Comments Box Plugin: FQL query on comment table by xid returns an empty array

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I expect [this FQL query](http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20xid%20FROM%20comment%20WHERE%20app_id%20=%20167964969883981%20AND%20xid%20=%20%27Product1%27) to return a non-empty array, because there are comments for that xid (see [here](http://www.sharesavespend.com/OurProducts/1/SBankKit.aspx)). In the app itself, I use Javascript to perform the FQL query inside of `window.fbAsyncInit` and after `FB.init({ //options });` like this:

```
var query = FB.Data.query("SELECT xid FROM comment WHERE app_id = " + facebookAppId + " and xid = '" + $this.attr("xid") + "'");
query.wait(function(rows) {
    // do things
});
```

Unfortunately this also returns an empty array (`[]`). This is bad because we need to use the comments count to decide whether to use the xid attribute (for comment boxes which already have comments) or the href attribute (for comment boxes which don't yet have comments). This will allow us to not lose comments that were made while we used the old-style xid attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you figured this out by now - I had the exactly same problem and [solved it finally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11192107/138526). In fact I found that you actually **must not** include the app_id. The key seems to be to get the correct access token (see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11192107/138526)).

hope it helps.